# Malloc memory for C string inside a structure

Tags: c, struct, char, malloc, pointers

I currently have the following code.

```
    struct qnode
    {
        char *path;
        struct qnode *next;
    }

    typedef struct qnode Node;
```

My code fails at this point however when I try to malloc space for for  within the struct qnode.

```
void add(Node *front, Node *back,char **path)
{
    /* Create the new node */
    Node *cur = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    /* Verify node successfully created */
    if(cur)
    {
            /* Populate Members of Node */
            cur->path = malloc(strlen(*path)); /* fails here */
            printf("Malloc path success");
            cur->path = *path;
```

I have verified that strlen is indeed operating on the correct pointer and it is indeed returning the length of size. For some reason though I get a segmentation fault at this point and I don't understand why.

F.y.i This is part of an assignment HOWEVER this simple line of malloc is not something that was specifically assigned neither was using the C language. I am allowed to do c++ on the assignment but i've chosen C to get some more knowledge about the language.

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: What is the type of `path`? Why are you discarding the pointer returned by the second `malloc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory. You need to leave room for the zero-terminator. You also must copy the contents of the string, not assign the pointer to the string. Both of these errors will lead to heap corruption and would explain your error. The code should be like this:

```
cur->path = malloc(strlen(*path)+1);
printf("Malloc path success");
strcpy(cur->path, *path);
```

You could of course use `strdup` if your system has it available, but note that it is not part of standard C.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realized I missed the strcpy part but forgot to go in and change that. My mistake was actually a simple little mistake further on but if you notice my "makeshift" debug statements are not exactly helpful as I forgot to include a \n to flush the output buffer so the message actually prints at the right time. Thanks for the help though! And I was unaware of strdup and I just verfied it is on my system which makes things a little bit easier. Also the value returned by strlen(*path) is indeed the actual size including '\0' as i've just investigated that as well.

Comment: Ben, you need to investigate your investigation. strlen definitely should NOT count the terminating '\0'.

Comment: @Ben Nigel is correct. `strlen` does not count any `\0` characters. You must have got that wrong.